# Why does dryer lint grill have wiring coming in?

Tags: electrical, dryer

I had to removey dryer's plastic lint grid to reach for something that got behind and noticed it has wires coming in (lower right).

[image]

What is the reason this seemingly simple piece of plastic has wires coming in?

Comment: Possibly static electricity discharge?

Comment: Also possible to thermostat to detect overheating due to blocked grille.

Comment: Could also be for moisture sensing

Comment: What does the manufacturer's maintenance manual say this connection is for? You can probably find that on line cheap or free....

Comment: If you provide the model # we won't be guessing about moisture + . Or over heat , or ESD. It could even be a flow sensor. These are all guesses that the brand and model would clear up.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly a moisture sensor.  Search YouTube for [dryer moisture sensor bar](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dryer+moisture+sensor+bar), and you should get a bunch of results showing how to replace them.

Answer (score 1):

That is the moisture sensor bar. When wet clothes tumbling in the dryer bridge the gap between the strips it tells the control the clothes are still wet and the dryer needs to run longer. There is nothing wrong with it, that is how it should be. Just put it back the way out was and you should be good.